# Can one temporarily remove some cells background colour when printing a LibreOffice Calc sheet

Tags: printing, libreoffice-calc

We have a rather complex LO Calc spreadsheet which uses background colours as visual cues for data entry.  However, we would really like to print the resulting document without these cues in the finished copy.  Is there any way to do this directly in LO without recourse to actual programming?

Comment: One thing you can try.  I don't know if this will mess up the background, so do it with an open copy that you don't save, so the change is temporary.  Top menu: Format | cells | Background tab | click No fill.  I don't know if this will override formatting of individual cells, and you may need to select all of the cells first.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Our requirement is naturally more complex than the simplified situation revealed here.  Consequently, having the target audience select cells or otherwise manipulate the spreadsheet prior to printing is not a practical solution.  We need some sort of function or macro that simply temporarily removes the background colour from a predetermined set of cells only when the sheet is printed.